# How to load KendoUI external templates on a ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I'm trying to load an KendoUIexternal template, I tried to follow the instructions in [this](http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/load-templates-external-files) page, but I can't seem to load my template. I get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:65097/Templates/_basicTemplates.html 404 (Not Found)
```

My Templates folder is inside my Views folder and looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/QafEmUgV).

The page that is trying to load it is inside the Views folder, at Home/Main.aspx, that file looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link href="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.common.min.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.default.min.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2012.3.1114/kendo.web.min.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc1.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3"></script>
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/index/templateLoader.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/index/main.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>



</head>
<body onload="GetMap();">
    <div id="canvasDiv" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: transparent; left: 10px; overflow:auto">
        <div id="mainDiv" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: transparent; left: 10px; overflow:auto">
            <div id="leftBar" style="border: thin solid #666666; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0; width: 180px; height: 100%; background-color: #ECFFFF; left: 10px; overflow:auto; z-index:20">
                <button id="btnUsuarios" value="Usuarios" style="position: absolute;left: 10px; right: 10px; top: 10px; width: auto; height: 50px" class="k-button" onclick="swapDiv(this)">Usuarios</button><br />
                <button id="btnRegiones" value="Regiones" style="position: absolute;left: 10px; right: 10px; top: 70px; width: auto; height: 50px" class="k-button" onclick="swapDiv(this)">Regiones</button><br />
                <button id="btnClusters" value="Clusters" style="position: absolute;left: 10px; right: 10px; top: 130px; width: auto; height: 50px" class="k-button" onclick="swapDiv(this)">Clusters</button><br />
                <button id="btnDispositivos" value="Dispositivos" style="position: absolute;left: 10px; right: 10px; top: 190px; width: auto; height: 50px" class="k-button" onclick="swapDiv(this)">Dispositivos</button><br />
                <button id="btnEventos" value="Eventos" style="position: absolute;left: 10px; right: 10px; top: 250px; width: auto; height: 50px" class="k-button" onclick="swapDiv(this)">Eventos</button><br />
            </div>
            <div id="selectionBar" style="border: thin solid #666666; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0; width: 180px; height: 100%; background-color: #DFF8FF; left: 10px; overflow:auto; z-index:9">
                <div class="k-toolbar k-grid-toolbar">
                    <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-add-button" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-add"></span>Agregar</a>
                </div>
                <div id="listView" ></div>
            </div>
            <div id='myMap' style="border: thin solid black; position: absolute; display: block; min-height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 189px; width: 88%; "></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        templateLoader.loadExtTemplate("../Templates/_basicTemplates.html");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I successfully load the template into my page? thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Uriel Arvizu: has referred to our solution, but now we'd like to suggest to use compiled KendoUI templates. [Here](http://www.nesterovsky-bros.com/weblog/2013/07/07/CompileKendoUITemplates.aspx) are the details.

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy way to load my templates, I found [this](http://www.nesterovsky-bros.com/weblog/2013/01/06/HowToLoadKendoUITemplatesFromExternalFiles.aspx) page and the .tt described there is an amazing way to load a templete from an external file. You just have to make sure the variable `root` is the correct string to the root location of all of your templates.